# SELECT DISTINCT or SELECT efficiency for IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle (if that matters).  Both of these Select statements will produce the same end result, but which one is quicker?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_A WHERE val IN (SELECT myField FROM tbl_B WHERE ... );
```

or would a SELECT DISTINCT in the sub-query be better?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_A WHERE val IN (SELECT DISTINCT myField FROM tbl_B WHERE ... );
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans?

Comment: I believe without distinct would be faster.. but its hard to say. Listen to what jarlh said.

Comment: And, yes, the product does matter. Different products optimize differently.

Comment: They are *functionally* the same. `IN(... subselect ...)` **implies** removing duplicates (and NULLs), so any sane optimiser would skip the extra DISTINCT.

Comment: Should be the same, the optimizer should be smart enough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM account_item WHERE instrument_id IN (SELECT instrument_id FROM instrument WHERE market_id=202)

SELECT * FROM account_item WHERE instrument_id IN (SELECT distinct instrument_id FROM instrument WHERE market_id=202)
```

The distinct makes no difference (as you might guessed), both gives this execution plan:

```
ALL_ROWS    SELECT STATEMENT   Cost = 703
1.1     HASH JOIN
2.1       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN PRF_INSTRUMENT_COMPANY
2.2       TABLE ACCESS FULL ACCOUNT_ITEM
```

What makes difference is:

1) cardinality of the subselect

```
SELECT * FROM account_item WHERE instrument_id IN (SELECT instrument_id FROM     instrument WHERE symbol='MSFT')

ALL_ROWS    SELECT STATEMENT   Cost = 129
1.1     HASH JOIN
2.1       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID INSTRUMENT
3.1         INDEX RANGE SCAN PRF_INSTRUMENT_MATCH
2.2       TABLE ACCESS FULL ACCOUNT_ITEM
```

2) whether you access to unindexed columns of tbl_A (aka select * hurts)

```
SELECT account_id FROM account_item WHERE instrument_id IN (SELECT distinct instrument_id FROM instrument WHERE market_id=202)

ALL_ROWS    SELECT STATEMENT   Cost = 608
1.1     HASH JOIN
2.1       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN PRF_INSTRUMENT_COMPANY
2.2       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN PRF_ACCOUNT_ITEM
```

3) and once you have good cardinality and accessing to columns which are in the indexes in use:

```
SELECT account_id FROM account_item WHERE instrument_id IN (SELECT instrument_id FROM instrument WHERE symbol='MSFT')

ALL_ROWS    SELECT STATEMENT   Cost = 33
1.1     HASH JOIN
2.1       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID INSTRUMENT
3.1         INDEX RANGE SCAN PRF_INSTRUMENT_MATCH
2.2       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN PRF_ACCOUNT_ITEM
```

Your query can be rewritten of using a join instead of a subselect.

```
select a.account_id
from   account_item a,
       instrument i
where a.instrument_id=i.instrument_id
and i.symbol='MSFT'

ALL_ROWS    SELECT STATEMENT   Cost = 33
1.1     HASH JOIN
2.1       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID INSTRUMENT
3.1         INDEX RANGE SCAN PRF_INSTRUMENT_MATCH
2.2       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN PRF_ACCOUNT_ITEM
```

With your example tables:

```
select a.* 
from tbl_A,tbl_B
where a.val=b.myField
and b...some other condition
```

The efficiency of subselect vs. join can fuel a new debate. Oracle is advertised so that it can convert in... subselect to joins, and as you can see, the execution plan is the same. However this is not always the case, depending on if you access to unindexed fields of tbl_a (account items), or the cardinality of the criteria on tbl_b (instruments) things can go quite weird.

Basically, the rule of thumb is:

- each column used in a where criteria must have indexed, preferrably not individually but as a set of columns covering all the columns used in where criteria, e.g. create index prf_fastInstruments on instrument(market_id,symbol)
- if you have a possibility to make an index unique, make it unique
- if you're about to touch lots of rows, such as "all payment records of the century", consider using a time criteria and put that to your index as well. This works as a poor man's partitioning and speed up queries
- limit the number of columns you load from the database. Usually select * is not really required. If you select only those columns which are indexed, the whole query is executed from the index, and needs to load *really* less data from the disk making your query blazing fast. But if you just select * or access even one additional unindexed column, that means that each matching row has to be loaded from the disk first.
- avoid premature optimizations (such as in... vs in distinct) - as you can see other factors have much bigger impact
- insert real data: real number of rows, with real cardinality (such as use a fake identity generator to create 1 million customers, but don't call them "user1"..."user100000") and do an execution plan on your selects before you change anything

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for the DISTINCT and generally speaking adding DISTINCT to a SELECT statement will increase the workload for the SQL Server.

Look at the query plan for both.  When you do the DISTINCT option do you get an additional SORT node?